# Add CORS filter in AppSync Subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, cors, aws-appsync

I am working on an app using AWS AppSync. I have enabled the AuthN and AuthZ.

One part I am stuck is at adding CORS filter for Appsync subscriptions.

I have worked on websockets earlier and there too I had this problem. I solved it manually in websockets by filtering the CORS from header during the handshake.

Do we have a provision to invoke a lambda in Appsync when a client is attempting to connect for subscription ?

Comment: did you check pipeline resolver with None Datasource?